# Определение или обстоятельство?

Tags: определения, обстоятельство

Он часто ездил на машине.
На машине - какой вопрос правилен: на чём? или как? И, соответственно, какой это член предложения?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

"На чём?" всё-таки будет более естественно. Шёл (как?) пешком, ехал (как?) верхом, но ехал (на чём?) на машине, на велосипеде, на лошади, на поезде. Дополнение.